# For loop in Scala - way of evaluation

Tags: scala, for-loop, optimization

I want to print integer numbers from 1 to a random integer number (e.g. to a random integer number < 10 like in the following case). I can use e.g. one from the following ways:

1)

```
val randomNumber=r.nextInt(10)
for (i <- 0 to randomNumber) {println(i)}
```

2)

```
for (i <- 0 to r.nextInt(10)) {println(i)}
```

My question is the following. Is there a difference between 1) and 2) in the sense of computation? It is clear that a random number `r.nextInt(10)` is computed only once and after that it is assigned to 
the variable `randomNumber` in the first case but what about the second case? Is the part `r.nextInt(10)` computed only once at the beginnig of the loop or it is computed for each iteration of the loop? If yes then the first variant is better from computation point of view? I know that this proposed example is an easy example but there can be much more complex `for` loops where the optimization can be very helpful. If the expression `r.nextInt(10)` in the second case is computed only once what about expressions which are e.g. functions of variable `i`, something like `for (i <- 0 to fce(i)) {println(i)}`? I guess that Fce(i) should be evaluated in every iteration of loop.

Thanks for help.
Andrew

Comment: You could test this fairly easily. Create a new function that returns a random number using `r.nextInt`, *but*, also have it print a message. Does it print multiple messages or just one?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no differences between 1) and 2).

The bound for the for loop will be evaluated once, and then the for loop will repeat this now fixed number of times.

Things would have been very different comparing those two pieces of code :

```
val randomNumber=r.nextInt(10)
for (i <- 0 to 10) {println(randomNumber)}
```

and

```
for (i <- 0 to 10) {println(r.nextInt(10))}
```

The first for loop will print 10 times the same value, the second will print 10 random values.

But you could still rewrite the second as

```
def randomNumber=r.nextInt(10)
for (i <- 0 to 10) {println(randomNumber)}
```

The change from a val to a function will cause a reevaluation every time the loop is executed.

Now, about

```
for (i <- 0 to function(i)) {doSomething()}
```

This doesn't compile. The variable i is only available in the scope between the {} of the for loop, and hence not for computing the loop bounds.

I hope this clarifies things a bit !

Comment: If it's ok for you, I invite you to accept an answer :-)

Comment: Definitely, but I will have to find out how..:-)

Comment: You should have a gray tick under the anwsers scores, which you can click to accept one.

Answer (score 1):

The two versions do the same thing, and to see why you need to realise that `for` in Scala works very differently from how it works in other languages like `C/C++`.

In Scala, `for` is just a bit of syntax that makes it easier to chain `map/foreach`, `flatMap`, and `withFilter` methods together. It makes functional code appear more like imperative code, but it is still executed in a functional way.

So your second chunk of code

```
for (i <- 0 to r.nextInt(10)) {println(i)}
```

is changed by the compiler into something like

```
(0 to r.nextInt(10)).foreach{ i => println(i) }
```

Looking at it this way, you can see that the range is computed first (using a single call to `nextInt`) and then `foreach` is called on that range. Therefore `nextInt` is called the same number of times as in your first chunk of code.